# Python2 webserver: Do not log request from localhost

Tags: python, python-2.7, webserver

The following Python2 webserver will log every single request including the one from localhost (127.0.0.1).

**webserver.py**

```
import SimpleHTTPServer, SocketServer, sys
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
port = 80
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", port), Handler)
sys.stderr = open('/home/user/log.txt', 'w', 1)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

As example; `curl localhost` (from the same machine) will produce the following log.

```
10.0.0.1  - - [10/Jan/2019 00:00:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2019 00:00:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2019 00:01:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2019 00:02:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

My question: Would it be possible to make an exception for local request? I don't want to log any request from localhost/127.0.0.1.

I'm thinking something like this but not really sure how to implement it in Python2 yet.

**webserver_v2_do_not_log_localhost.py**

```
import webserver.py # webserver code above, or simply paste everything in here.

if SourceIPAddress == 127.0.0.1:
    print('DO NOT log request from localhost/127.0.0.1')
    # Script here
else:
    print('Log everything')
    # Script here
```

Any idea on the scripts would be highly appreciated. Thanks

**Desired Output** when performing `tail -F log.txt` (external IP only, not localhost)

```
10.0.0.1  - - [10/Jan/2019 00:00:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Sure it's possible, seem like you got it. What is your issue? 
You can implement it in a lot ways...you want an example for the 'Script'?

Comment: That's right @Green. Any idea on the scripts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I added an answer which look a bit more elegant than this..(:
and there is a lot of other valid way you could achieve it, I added some good links you can check

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logging.Filter`class.
When you declare your logger, do something like that:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.INFO)
class Global:
    SourceIPAddress = ''


class IpFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):#the rec is part of the function signature.
        return not Global.SourceIPAddress == '127.0.0.1'


def main():



    log = logging.getLogger('myLogger')
    log.addFilter(IpFilter())
    log.info("log")
    Global.SourceIPAddress = '127.0.0.1'
    log.info("Don't log")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Of course I implemented it in a very simple way and you should save the IP in a better place(:

I would also check this links for more info:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/3364/logging.Filter

Comment: I tried your code and combine it with the webserver code above, however, I still can see local ip address in the log

`user@linux:~/$ tail -F log.txt 
10.1.1.10 - - [17/Jan/2019 12:10:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2019 13:31:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2019 13:33:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2019 13:33:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: I guess you did it wrong, how do you check the condition of the ip? do you referencing to the same `SourceIPAddress` variable?

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand where you got it wrong without your code. If you will add the relevant part with the logger config and the IP assignment I can take a look. But first, try to debug it and see why it's failing on the condition. Maybe it's not a string (very likely) but an IP object or something.